# Exception thrown at 0x001036CA in 14423 Lab 05 COAL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000FFFFE

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
    Message BYTE "Enter Number ",0
    Arr DWORD 5 DUP(0)
    Divi DWORD 4
    GreaterNum DWORD 0
    Outerloopholder DWORD 0
.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, 1
    mov eax, 0
    .while(ecx<6)
        mov edx, offset message
        call WriteString
        inc eax
        call WriteInt
        dec eax
        call crlf
        mov ebx, eax
        call ReadInt
        imul ebx, 4
        mov Arr[ebx], eax
        mov eax, ebx
        sub edx, edx
        div Divi
        inc ecx
        inc eax
    .endw
    
    mov ecx, 4
    Greater:
        imul ecx, 4
        mov ebx, Arr[ecx]
        mov eax, ecx
        sub edx, edx
        div Divi
        mov Outerloopholder, eax
        mov ecx, Outerloopholder
        dec ecx
        GreaterAgain:
            imul ecx, 4
            mov eax, Arr[ecx]
            CMP ebx, eax
            jl Changer
            mov eax, ecx
            sub edx, edx
            div Divi
            mov ecx, eax
            loop GreaterAgain
            
        Changer:
            mov eax, Arr[ecx]
            mov edx, eax
            mov GreaterNum, edx
            mov eax, ecx
            sub edx, edx
            div Divi
            mov ecx, eax
            loop GreaterAgain

        mov ecx, Outerloopholder
        loop Greater

        mov eax, GreaterNum
        call WriteInt

        
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

I am assigned to a task to take user input in an array and find the maximum but i couldn't do that because of the above error that says access violation of reading address

Comment: please format the code so it does display correctly

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? Visual Studio Community has a free debugger that works very well. OllyDbg is used by many people as well.